# Angular2 Breeze: How can I replace the default http service of breezejs in order to append some logic to the server call methods?

Tags: angular, breeze

I already created a wrapper service for @angular/Http to add the logic of Bearer authentication and a counter of Http Requests.

I want to use this custom service to replace the breeze's one.
How to accomplish this?

This is a simplest version of my wrapper

```js
@import {Injectable} from '@angular/core'
import {Http, Headers} from '@angular/Http'
import {AuthService} from './auth.service'

@Injectable()
export class AuthHttpService
{
  constructor(private http: Http, private authService: AuthService){}
  get = (url: string){
    
    //some logic for bearer authenticated calls 
    let params = {
      // request extra info
    };

    return this.http.get(url, params);
  }
}
```

My breeze manager fabric service. You can see authentication bearer logic. I want to the bearer appending code and change the entire Breeze's Http service.

```js
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Http, Response } from '@angular/http';
import { Observable, Scheduler } from 'rxjs/Rx';
import { LocalStorage, SessionStorage } from 'ng2-webstorage';
import { config, NamingConvention, EntityManager, EntityQuery, DataService, MetadataStore } from 'breeze-client';
import { AuthenticationService } from '../authentication/authentication.service';
import { BreezeProvider } from './breeze.provider.service';


import { Constants } from '../constants.class';


@Injectable()
export class EntityManagerProvider {
    constructor(private provider: BreezeProvider, authenticationService: AuthenticationService) {
        
        NamingConvention.camelCase.setAsDefault();
        let ajaxAdapter = <any>config.getAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
        let headers = ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] || {};
        headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authenticationService._userData.accessToken;
        ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] = headers;
    }
}
```

Comment: This is what DI is for. Just `provide` your own version for HTTP.

Comment: I'll explain me a little more. Breeze use a default Http provider and I want to replace it with my wrapper. Is not about DI is about how breezejs replacement mechanism works. Please, read all the question and think about before any negative vote.

Comment: Then perhaps you could expand on the current configuration; are you using the bridge? Add a [mcve] to show how you're using it.

Answer (score 2):

I have been looking for any example when found this snipplet at breeze Doc site:

```js
angular.module('app').run(['$http', function($http) {
    var ajax = breeze.config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
    ajax.setHttp($http); // use the $http instance that Angular injected into your app.
}]);
```

This example is for angularjs but help me to understand the replacement
for

```
    let ajaxAdapter = <any>config.getAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
```

changed to

```
    let ajaxAdapter = <any>config.getAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
    ajaxAdapter.http = authService;
```

and remove hard coded bearer lines

```
    //let headers = ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] || {};
    //headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authenticationService._userData.accessToken;
    //ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] = headers;
```

**Update**

---

I did reverse of commented lines for update default settings  of breeze because angular/http methods use the default settings. So, Bearer authentication was keeped at default settings and other logic staff at custom http provider.

The entire logic is as:

```
    // Provider replacement
    let ajaxAdapter = <any>config.getAdapterInstance('ajax', 'angular');
    ajaxAdapter.http = authService;

    //Default authentication settings  
    let headers = ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] || {};
    headers['Authorization'] = 'Bearer ' + authenticationService._userData.accessToken;
    ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] = headers;
```

Comment: Following part was really helpful: let headers = ajaxAdapter.defaultSettings['headers'] || {}

Answer (score 0):

Related to Angular (2/4), I found most of what I needed to get this working by looking at how Leonardo was approaching it in his answer and this discussion by Ward Bell and team [here:](https://github.com/Breeze/breeze.js/issues/173#issuecomment-263229251).

Basically, replacing the ajax adapter with your own authorized version that has the bearer token included.

Per Ward:

> `import { AjaxAngular2Adapter } from 'breeze-bridge-angular2';   ...`
>
> ```
> // assume you injected auth0Http instance when you get here ...
> config.registerAdapter('ajax', () => new AjaxAngular2Adapter(auth0Http));
> config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', AjaxAngular2Adapter.adapterName, true);  ...
> ```

In my specific case, this meant changing my entity manager provider and also injecting my authService:

```
if (this.authService.isAuthenticated()) {
                config.registerAdapter('ajax', () => new AjaxAngular2Adapter(<any>this.authService.authHttp));
                config.initializeAdapterInstance('ajax', AjaxAngular2Adapter.adapterName, true);
            }

// Unrelated, but including for context....
let dsconfig: DataServiceOptions = {
                serviceName: EntityManagerProvider.serviceName
            };
let dataService = new DataService(dsconfig);

let masterManager = EntityManagerProvider._masterManager = new EntityManager({
                dataService: dataService
            });
```

I'm still trying to work the the case where the user isn't authenticated when the entity manager provider isn't created, but later logs in. There is some discussion about not throwing the jwt error in the link, but I haven't entirely figured that out yet.

Comment: I found enough to suppress my Jwt missing or expired error here: https://github.com/auth0/angular2-jwt. This also allowed me to remove my "if authenticated" statement in the code above and always push my authHttp provider into the breeze entity manager, it just silently fails if the user isn't authenticated (assuming the breeze endpoint doesn't require authorization).